# absl-py save and ignore unrecongized flags

Tags: absl-py

Sometimes I have to pass flags to the python script such as `--local_rank` in addition to the prespecified ones in absl-py. Is there a way to -

- ignore unspecified flags
- save pre- and un-specified flags in json as dictionary